# AJAX deeplinking with jQuery Address

Tags: jquery, ajax, deep-linking, jquery-address

I have a website which has many pages:

> For example:
>
> HOME: `http://mywebsite.com/index.html`
>
> SOME PAGE: 
>   `http://mywebsite.com/categorie/somepage.html`

I decided to make my pages load dynamically with AJAX without reloading the page. So I decided to use *jQuery Address* plugin ( http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/ ) in order to allow deeplinking and Back-Forward navigation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploads/scripts/jquery.address-1.2rc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $('a').address(function() {
                    return $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');
                });
</script>
```

Now, after installing the plugin, if I go on `http://mywebsite.com/index.html` *(HOME)* and click on *SOME PAGE* link, jquery successfully loads the `http://mywebsite.com/categorie/somepage.html` without reloading the page and the address bar on my browser displays: 
`http://mywebsite.com/index.html/#/categorie/somepage.html` which is great!

However, **the problem** is: if I copy this dynamically generated URL: `http://mywebsite.com/index.html/#/categorie/somepage.html`
into a web browser address bar, it will take into my website *index.html* page and not to the "SOME PAGE" page. Also, The Forward/Back buttons don't work correctly, they only replace the address in the URL bar but the content stays the same.

I suppose that I need to write some JavaScript rule that associates the dynamic URL with the correct page?

Some help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Something to consider: What if a user without JavaScript accesses such a link?

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing... Maybe a .htaccess redirect rule?

Answer (score 2):

copy paste url to address bar is working
back/next button also working.

the **#** should be there to make it work

anyone know how to make **#!** so its indexable by google?

or **#/** is the same thing?

basically this work for me on wordpress:

```
// ajax setup
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false, success: function() { 
// optional action here
}});  

// Event handlers
$.address.init(function(event) {
  $('#nav li a').address(function() {
  return $(this).attr('href').replace(location.pathname, '');
   });
 }).bind('externalChange', {}, function(event) {
    var post_id; // get page id
    var nav_id; // get nav class
    // for back button 
    switch (true) {
     case (event.value == undefined):
           post_id = 2; nav_id = 'home'; break;
     case (event.value == "/about"):
           post_id = 19; nav_id = 'about'; break;
     case (event.value == "/product"):
           post_id = 26; nav_id = 'product'; break;

    ...etc....

     default: post_id = 2; nav_id = 'home';
    }

    // content loader on back/next button
    $("#content-wrap").load("http://www.somesite.com/home/",{id:post_id}); // load content
 });   

 // content loader by #nav 
 $(document).on("click","#nav li a",function(e){                                         
   var post_id = $(this).attr("id"); // get page id   
   $("#content-wrap").load("http://www.somesite.com/home/",{id:post_id}); // load content  
   return false; // keep url, no refresh
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var path = location.hash.substring(1); // remove '#'
    if (path) {
        $.address.value(path);
    }
});
```

**Update:**

If you're loading pages manually (e.g. on link click) instead of using an address event handler (e.g. `$.address.change(function () { ... })`), then replace the `$.address.value(path);` above with an Ajax call for the page at `path`:

```
$(function () {
    var path = location.hash.substring(1); // remove '#'
    if (path) {
        // get page at path
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand.
However, I found another plugin, which seems to offer the same thing:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ this one works using a via hashchange event. I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it indexable by Google (#!) by adding:
    $.address.crawlable(true);
Here is a link I found helpful for jQuery Address methods:
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/